# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Stuck with this error for days

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to make migrations in my model but stuck with this error:

*django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'posts_article' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key: posts_article.author_id contains a value '1' that does not have a corresponding value in posts_author.id.*

Here's my models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.utils.timezone import now

User = get_user_model()

# Create your models here.
class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
    

class Topic(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    overview = models.TextField(null=True)
    content = models.TextField(null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Topic, blank=True, null=True)
    #featured = models.BooleanField(None, default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-updated', '-created']
```

I've searched the internet and tried a few solutions but it's the same. I am totally out of solutions. I am new to Django so please don't be too hard on me :)

Comment: Can you share the migration that is failing? I would also be quite worried if it works one day and fails another one :)

Comment: Did you by any chance add `on_delete=models.SET_NULL` afterwards?  The error is saying you have an `Article` instance with an `Author` with a **pk = 1**, but there is no `Author` with that primary key anymore.  `on_delete=models.SET_NULL` should set the `author` field to `NULL` if the `Author` is deleted, but if you added that afterwards, then the `author` field would **not** have been set to `NULL`, and would have remained as **1**.  If you have no important data in your tables yet, you could try deleting the `Article` with the bad `author` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error in data inconsistency, not in your code. Try delete all your data and migrations (i think, your project in early developmentm, not in production?)

Run `manage.py flush` for remove all data from tables. Or you can phisically remove you database. Then recreate all with `manage.py makemigrations && manage.py migrate`.